# Как сменить курсор на winapi?

Tags: c, winapi

Как на Си сменить форму курсора на одну из стандартных, когда он перемещается на определённые координаты? Я почитал на эту тему и понял, что надо использовать LoadCursor и SetCursor. Но в каком месте кода включить LoadCursor? В WinMain или где-то в обработчике сообщения?

Answer (score 3):

LoadCursor() имеет смысл сделать при старте приложения -- если он свой лежит в ресурсах. Стандартный курсор можно загрузить в любой момент.

SetCursor() делается в ответ на сообщение WM_SETCURSOR.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648380(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Displaying_a_Cursor

Comment: Цитата:"Стандартный курсор можно загрузить в любой момент." Но для повышения быстродействия где лучше? В WinMain?

Comment: Не думаю что это окажет хоть какое-то влияние на быстродействие. Да, обычно такие вещи делаются в WinMain до основного цикла обработки сообщений.